# Connecting arduino to existing pcb power grid

Tags: arduino, power, drawing

I have an idea about a project to control a device with the help of Arduino+wifi shield and an android app.

The device that is to be controlled, already has its own power supply. Internally it provides* a regular 5 v dc to the PCB grid (*well, that's my guess, since most electronic components run at 5v dc. I haven't actually measured it with multimeter). What I want to know is if I can integrate my Arduino(with wifi shield) with the device "drawing power from the same" 5 v PCB grid?

Comment: What is the voltage source?

Comment: [Power grid](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Qatar,_power_lines_%287%29.JPG). Don't hook your Arduino up to that.

Comment: You need to figure out what the voltage is that the device power supply provides, and what the current is that it can supply.  You *guess* that it supplies 5V, but 12V is a common voltage for analog devices and power devices, 3.3V is common for digital devices, +/-15V is common for amplifiers and other analog type devices, etc.  You should measure it.

Comment: You can use a spare disk power cable which should provide +5V and +12V.  If no cables are free you can get a tee cable to provide an extra connector.

Comment: Thank you all. Sure pipe, won't hook it up to 'the' power grid :D.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is 5V, the main problem would be the current the device can provide,  beyond what it needs.  Your Arduino and wifi shield will likely take up to 400 mA by themselves at peak. If the device uses 700mA and it's internal regulator can only do 1A, then you would be over driving it. If it's directly powered by a external supply, you could replace the supply with a beefier one.

But stop assuming and measure the voltage.

Comment: Thanks Passerby for the reply. I will measure and share result with you. Since I am not much into electronics will need some time... might still need further help on this. will come back to you soon. thanks again.